# How to right-align an incomplete CSS Grid row?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have an unknown number of items that will display in a grid. When a row is incomplete, like the second row shown in the screenshots, I need the items to align to the right.

[image: Codepen screenshot]

I can achieve the effect with `direction: rtl`, but that changes the order of the items, which I don't want to do.

[image: Codepen screenshot]

How can I do this? Codepen available here to troubleshoot: https://codepen.io/keefblurgu/pen/gOvzWbw

Edit: Stack Snippet added

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
}

.grid > div {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: coral
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not believe this is possible without a defined number of columns.

Comment: There's a "hacky" solution I've been playing with using `last-child` but I'm stuck getting the number 6 box to flow correctly at certain screen sizes but if you have an unknown number of items then this probably wouldn't work for you anyway. https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/nL2z7bx3/

Comment: Not currently supported. You can place items in a grid manually, but only if the number of columns is known.

Answer (score 0):

I had this question as well. Assuming Brett Donald's comment is correct, and this is not currently supported, others might find the solution below helpful. It's a not-too-crazy hack; ~12 lines of JavaScript that should work if you have a grid with a fixed number of columns. It uses VueJS, but is hopefully clear enough for those unfamiliar with Vue. The key ideas are:

(1) Create an array of index values for each element in the grid using the final order you want to see - e.g., `array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`.

(2) Sort the array so that each row of index values is reversed, and thus will appear in the correct order in the final grid layout.

(3) Use the sorted array to re-order the  elements.

(4) Use `direction: rtl;` to right-align the  elements. They now are shown with the correct ordering.

```
<template>
  <main>
    <div v-for="i in array">{{ i }}</div>
  </main>
</template>

<script setup>
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
(function () {
  array.reverse();
  const length = array.length;
  const columns = 5;
  const groups = Math.ceil(length / columns);
  for (let i = 0; i < groups; i++) {
    const startIndex = Math.max(0, length - (i + 1) * columns);
    const endIndex = length - i * columns;
    const group = array.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
    group.reverse();
    array.splice(startIndex, group.length, ...group);
  }
})();
array.reverse();
</script>

<style scoped>
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  direction: rtl;
  gap: 1rem;
}
div {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: coral;
}
</style>
```

[Right-aligned grid of  elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tELgH.png)

Comment: I appreciate your effort here, but if you’re defining the number of columns and/or items, then there are lots of other ways to create a layout like this. We also shouldn’t be using ‘direction: rtl’ in this way since it’s meant for users whose language reads right-to-left and not for our layout hacks 